# Jaybird driver difficulty, cannot connect to firebird server

Tags: java, firebird, jaybird, firebird-3.0

I've been trying to connect to a localhost firebird server via Netbeans IDE. When I test the connection I get a connection rejected by remote interface error. I tried to connect using the password masterkey and my personal password but to no avail.

I would also like to know where to put the jaybird22 DLL files that came with the zip package, perhaps the problem is caused because the dll files are not in the proper folder yet. Please view the added screenshot of netbeans to see what address I was using and to see the full error message.

Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Unless you want to use Firebird embedded, or use the native protocol, you don't need to use jaybird22.dll at all (and the .so is the equivalent for Linux, so you don't need that either). Are you sure you are using Firebird 2.5, and not Firebird 3? A possible cause of this error is that the Firebird server doesn't have permission to access the database file.

Comment: Hello, We were using firebird 3 and it was firebird 3 that was causing the problem for some reason. I installed firebird 2.5.5 and now it connects just fine, so i guess the problem is solved. Thanks for the reply though!

Comment: The Firebird 3 problem is caused by the new security features of Firebird, check https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/jaybird/wiki/Jaybird-and-Firebird-3 for instructions on how to configure Firebird 3 so it works with Jaybird 2.2.